# CoffeeScript and Cake

Tags: macos, coffeescript, osx-mountain-lion

I installed CoffeeScript on my machine with `npm install -g coffee-script` I get the following message when I check cake version:

```
$ coffee -v
CoffeeScript version 1.3.3
[~]
$ cake -v
path.existsSync is now called `fs.existsSync`.

/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:108
    throw new Error("Cakefile not found in " + (process.cwd()));
          ^
Error: Cakefile not found in /Users/Phil
    at cakefileDirectory (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:108:11)
    at cakefileDirectory (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:106:14)
    at cakefileDirectory (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:106:14)
    at Object.exports.run (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:49:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/cake:7:38)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
```

Does anyone know how can I fix this?

Comment: create `Cakefile` in that dir? `/Users/Phil`

Comment: yeah, I'm new to this, what is supposed to be in the cake file?

Comment: check this [link](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/[HowTo]-Compiling-and-Setting-Up-Build-Tools) section: 'An Empty Cakefile' .. good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues here.

The first is a known issue which causes:

```
path.existsSync is now called `fs.existsSync`
```

You can find out more about the issue here:
https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/pull/2411

As stated in the pull request, it should be fixed in the coffee-script master branch.  So you can download the latest source from GitHub and it should resolve the issue for you.

Otherwise, try installing an older version of node:
http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.6.6/

The second issue which is addressed in other answers, is the need for a Cakefile in the directory that you are running the cake command in.

Answer (score 0):

Cakefile should be exists in directory where you call cake

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue in cakephp3. The other solution here didn't work. I was trying to bake plugin from the command line.

> cake bake Plugin PageManager

After receiving above error, I changed my command to following and it worked like a charm:

> ./cake bake plugin PageManager